# LWJGL My Camera class stops rotating

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I am programming a Camera class for my 3D game. I implemented a way of resetting the y rotation to 0 after reaching 360, but for some reason, after I rotate 3 or 4 times, my character just stops turning... I have no idea why! Here is the source code where I think the problem is going on:

```
        mouseX = Mouse.getX();
        mouseY = Mouse.getY();

        float finalMouseX = (mouseX - previousMouseX);
        float finalMouseY = (mouseY - previousMouseY);

        if (rotation.y + finalMouseX >= 360) {

            rotation.y = rotation.y + finalMouseX - 360;

        } else if (rotation.y + finalMouseX < 0) {

            rotation.y = 360 - rotation.y + finalMouseX;

        } else {

            rotation.y += finalMouseX;

        } 

        if (rotation.x - finalMouseY >= -89 && rotation.x - finalMouseY <= 89) {

            rotation.x += -finalMouseY;

        } else if (rotation.x - finalMouseY < -89) {

            rotation.x = -89;

        } else if (rotation.x - finalMouseY > 89) {

            rotation.x = 89;

        }
```

Comment: I think in this case you should post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: It has a huge library of voxel's and file loading stuff... I could try.

Comment: at least post the entire code of this class and the code that calls this method

Comment: Shouldn't that be a + instead of a - after 360, inside the first else?

Comment: @DavidWallace: I recommend posting this as an answer.

Comment: I don't like posting an answer when I don't know what the code is trying to do.